# Getting text from text views inside all collection view cells at once

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a collection view and I'm using a custom class for the cells. Each cell is the height and width of the main view and each cell has a text view, here is the code:

```
class CustomWriterPageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    fileprivate let textViewOne: UITextView = {

        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.backgroundColor = .cyan
        tv.text = "Chapter Title"
        tv.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 27)
        tv.textColor = .gray
        return tv

    }()
}
```

I've got a button on my view controller, what I want it to do is that when I tap on that button, I want the text in all my cells to get printed. Is this possible? I've done what I could but It only prints the initial text ("Chapter Title") that the text views contain and only prints the text of the visible cell. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc func printButtonTapped() {

        let cv = CustomWriterPageCell()
        print(cv.textViewOne.text)
        // Prints- Chapter Title 
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowlayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WriterPageCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomWriterPageCell

        cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 1 ? .green : .yellow

        return cell
    }

}
```

Is it possible to print all the text in all the cells at once?

Comment: can you show your cellforItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember you from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977396/how-to-access-text-views-in-custom-collection-view-cell-class-from-the-main-clas). A little change to my previous answer will help you. In your previous question you set the `CustomWriterPageCell` as `UITextView`'s delegate. Instead of that, this time, set your Controller as the delegate.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WriterPageCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomWriterPageCell

    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 1 ? .green : .yellow
    cell.textViewOne.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Now, conform to the protocol:

```
extension ViewController : UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

      let text = textView.text 
  }
```

}

Until now, you successfully transferred the text from a TextView in a cell to your Controller.
Now the problem here is that you don't know this text belongs to which indexPath.

I'm not saying this is the best solution, but it works safely in your case:
You can set a tag for each TextView which acts like an id:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WriterPageCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomWriterPageCell

    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.item % 2 == 1 ? .green : .yellow
    cell.textViewOne.delegate = self
    cell.textViewOne.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
```

}

Then:

```
extension ViewController : UITextViewDelegate {
   func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
       let text = textView.text //This the text
       let row = textView.tag //This the indexPath.row
       self.texts[row] = text //Save texts in an array. This array is fixed-size and has number of elements equal to your number of collection view's Items.

}
```

You can declare it like this in your Controller :
`var texts = Array(repeating: "", count: 10)` where 10 is the number of items in Collection View.

Everything is set up, let's get to your print button:

```
 @objc func printButtonTapped() {

       for text in self.texts {

            print(text)

       }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer, its working, but now the problem is, what I wanted in my previous question stopped working, any way you could make both work?

Comment: Yes, I can make both work ;) I'll edit my answer after I'm finished with my stuff.

Comment: Heyy I figured it out, thanks to you. you the man! Also, if you don’t mind me asking, how did you learn swift? Courses or???

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you made it. I've started off by watching Mark Price Udemy's videos. They are great.

Comment: Hey, do you know how to fix the cell duplicating problem? It's happening because of dequeuReuseableCell but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

If you already set up your data source and you have array of all texts which is shown on your cells then you can print all of them at once by accessing the data itself, like so: -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   fileprivate var texts = [String]()

    @objc func printButtonTapped() {
       texts.forEach { (text) in
                      print(text)
                    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't have an array setup, could you tell me how to do that, Im sorry i'm not very good at swift

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model, for example

```
struct YourModel {
    var content = "" // Content is what's displayed in your cell
}
```

Then you also need an array to manage your models in your controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var yourModels = [YourModel]()
}
```

The array yourModels will be used to display into your tableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomWriterPageCell, self.yourModels.count > indexPath.row else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.config(byYourModel: self.yourModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}
```

Config your cell

```
 class CustomWriterPageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        fileprivate let textViewOne: UITextView = {

            let tv = UITextView()
            tv.backgroundColor = .cyan
            tv.text = "Chapter Title"
            tv.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 27)
            tv.textColor = .gray
            return tv

        }()

        func config(byYourModel model: YourModel) {
            self.textView.text = model.content
        }
    }
```

And then if you want to print all

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @objc func printButtonTapped() {

        for model in self.yourModels {
            print(model.content)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm talking about collection view not table view

Comment: Same way for collection view, you just need an array to manager your model. Then you can do anything with those models (e.g: print out the value for this case)

Comment: What is the replacement for this line, this gives an error : cell.config(byYourModel: self.yourModels[indexPath.row])

Comment: what error you got? Please notice that you can use different class, function name by your style, my ones are just example.

Comment: Value of type 'CustomWriterPageCell' has no member 'config'

Comment: You need define function `func config(byYourModel model: YourModel) {}` in your `CustomWriterPageCell ` @SMALLworld